# Energy level photon spectra for different atoms

Tags: photons, electrons, atomic-physics, wavelength, atoms

I'm trying to determine the photon emission wavelength ranges for different atoms.

For hydrogen, it's super simple. We use the $$ E_n = -\frac{13.6}{n^2} $$

Then, if we want to see the wavelength of photon emitted from $n=3$ to $n=2$, we do $$E_Δ = E_3 - E_2$$ $$ E_Δ = \frac{hc}{λ}$$ $$ λ = \frac{hc}{E_Δ}$$

I'd like to do the same for other atoms, such as carbon, but I don't know the energy level formula. would the following be the correct one where Z is atomic number and for carbon, we put 6 ? $$ E_n = \frac{-13.6 * Z^2}{n^2}$$

I'm not fully sure about this as due to more than 1 electron in the atom, it might be more complicated than that. Would appreciate the easy explanation as I'm not skilled in this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such equation. Finding the energy levels of atoms with multiple electrons is very complicated. It is an advanced topic in quantum mechanics, and finding ways to do it more accurately is a subject of research. Not all physical phenomena have simple formulae that describe them.